# Is it a must to get identations before the yaml array item line?

Tags: arrays, yaml

Here is the examples (from https://www.json2yaml.com/), almost everywhere use this style.

```
    json:
      - rigid
      - better for data interchange
    yaml: 
      - slim and flexible
      - better for configuration
    object:
        key: value
      array:
        - null_value:
        - boolean: true
        - integer: 1
        - alias: &example aliases are like
```

while in k8s templetes, there are no extra identations.

```
status:
  addresses:
  - address: 10.211.55.6
    type: InternalIP
  - address: ubuntu-1
    type: Hostname
```

I wonder which is correct ?

Comment: The [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#61-indentation-spaces) says that _a block style construct is terminated when encountering a line which is less indented than the construct._

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. You *can* indent block sequence items further but are not required to.